Neo4j error while creating graph database
typellm_type = os.getenv("LLM_TYPE", "ollama")
if llm_type == "ollama":
    llm = ChatOllama(model="llama3.1", temperature=0)
else:
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4o-mini")
llm_transformer = LLMGraphTransformer(llm=llm)

graph_documents = llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents(documents)

graph_documents[0]
GraphDocument(nodes=[Node(id='maternal chronic renal failure', type='Disease'), Node(id='sextigesta', type='Medical Condition'), Node(id='pregnancy', type='Event'), Node(id='patient', type='Person'), Node(id='regional hospital', type='Hospital'), Node(id='week 27+2', type='Time Period')], relationships=[Relationship(source=Node(id='patient', type='Person'), target=Node(id='sextigesta', type='Medical Condition'), type='IS_A'), Relationship(source=Node(id='patient', type='Person'), target=Node(id='maternal chronic renal failure', type='Disease'), type='HAS_CONDITION'), Relationship(source=Node(id='patient', type='Person'), target=Node(id='regional hospital', type='Hospital'), type='IS_ADMISSIONED_TO'), Relationship(source=Node(id='pregnancy', type='Event'), target=Node(id='maternal chronic renal failure', type='Disease'), type='HAS_RISK_FACTOR'), Relationship(source=Node(id='pregnancy', type='Event'), target=Node(id='week 27+2', type='Time Period'), type='IS_AT_STAGE')], source=Document(metadata={'source': 'text_files_en/S2254-28842017000200184-1.txt'}, page_content='A 45-year-old patient, sextigesta, with high-risk pregnancy due to maternal chronic renal failure, was admitted to a regional hospital, from a regional hospital, due to threatened preterm labor at week 27+2, with tocolytic treatment.'))


graph.add_graph_documents(
    graph_documents,
    baseEntityLabel=True,
    include_source=True



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 graph.add_graph_documents(
      2     graph_documents,
      3     baseEntityLabel=True,
      4     include_source=True
      5 )

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/graphs/neo4j_graph.py:583, in Neo4jGraph.add_graph_documents(self, graph_documents, include_source, baseEntityLabel)
    581     node.type = _remove_backticks(node.type)
    582 # Import nodes
--> 583 self.query(
    584     node_import_query,
    585     {
    586         "data": [el.__dict__ for el in document.nodes],
    587         "document": document.source.__dict__,
    588     },
    589 )
    590 # Import relationships
    591 self.query(
    592     rel_import_query,
    593     {
   (...)
    607     },
    608 )

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/graphs/neo4j_graph.py:420, in Neo4jGraph.query(self, query, params)
    418 try:
    419     data = session.run(Query(text=query, timeout=self.timeout), params)
--> 420     json_data = [r.data() for r in data]
    421     if self.sanitize:
    422         json_data = [value_sanitize(el) for el in json_data]

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/graphs/neo4j_graph.py:420, in <listcomp>(.0)
    418 try:
    419     data = session.run(Query(text=query, timeout=self.timeout), params)
--> 420     json_data = [r.data() for r in data]
    421     if self.sanitize:
    422         json_data = [value_sanitize(el) for el in json_data]

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/work/result.py:378, in Result.__iter__(self)
    376     yield self._record_buffer.popleft()
    377 elif self._streaming:
--> 378     self._connection.fetch_message()
    379 elif self._discarding:
    380     self._discard()

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_common.py:178, in ConnectionErrorHandler.__getattr__.<locals>.outer.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
    176 def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    177     try:
--> 178         func(*args, **kwargs)
    179     except (Neo4jError, ServiceUnavailable, SessionExpired) as exc:
    180         assert not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(self.__on_error)

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_bolt.py:860, in Bolt.fetch_message(self)
    856 # Receive exactly one message
    857 tag, fields = self.inbox.pop(
    858     hydration_hooks=self.responses[0].hydration_hooks
    859 )
--> 860 res = self._process_message(tag, fields)
    861 self.idle_since = monotonic()
    862 return res

# File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_bolt5.py:370, in Bolt5x0._process_message(self, tag, fields)
    368 self._server_state_manager.state = self.bolt_states.FAILED
    369 try:
--> 370     response.on_failure(summary_metadata or {})
    371 except (ServiceUnavailable, DatabaseUnavailable):
    372     if self.pool:

File ~/Downloads/GraphRAG-with-Llama-3.1-main/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_common.py:245, in Response.on_failure(self, metadata)
    243 handler = self.handlers.get("on_summary")
    244 Util.callback(handler)
--> 245 raise Neo4jError.hydrate(**metadata)

ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.create.addLabels`: Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.IllegalTokenNameException: '' is not a valid token name. Token names cannot be empty or contain any null-bytes.}
 

I am trying to upload the text of a file document in neo4j to create a graphic knowledge base for RAG.
Fo this particular document, I am encountering the error
ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke procedure apoc.create.addLabels: Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.IllegalTokenNameException: '' is not a valid token name. Token names cannot be empty or contain any null-bytes.}
please help.
